# Can't find the "Create prev/next controls" option

Tags: javascript

I created a slideshow using the Field slideshow module. However, I can't find the Create prev/next controls. Any tips on where they are located?

Oh, and I can't see the "Slideshow" option under Format in the Manage Display window for the newly created content type of Slideshow...

Comment: Make sure your field type is Image not File

Comment: Field type is set to Image :(

Comment: Clear your cache please

Comment: Cleared the cache just now. 
Rendered file
Image
Hidden

are the only three options I've bot under Format. There is no Slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the **manage display** tab of desired content type.

Choose the format to Slideshow.

Here is a Great [Tutotrial](http://drupalquests.blogspot.in/2012/01/drupal-7-create-slideshow-inside.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I don't have Slideshow as an option in the dropdown menu :(